# What are the differences between Concepts and Contracts?

Tags: c++, c++20

- Concepts are an extension to the templates feature provided by the C++ programming language. Concepts are named Boolean predicates on template parameters, evaluated at compile time. A concept may be associated with a template (class template, function template, or member function of a class template), in which case it serves as a constraint: it limits the set of arguments that are accepted as template parameters.
- Contracts have enabled annotating functions with predicates, expressed as C++ expressions, citing as many as practical of the requirements imposed on callers of the function, about argument values passed and the state of the program; and of details of results promised, both the value returned and the state of the program after.

Could you please give several concrete examples to explain the differences?

Comment: Concepts are a compile-time feature and deals with types. Contracts are similar to exceptions, the idea is to give pre-condition, post-conditions and asserts to functions. This will be checked at run-time and call a violation handler if anything goes wrong. Contracts can then be turned on or off when the program is compiled. Much like `NDEBUG` and assert. [Here's a read](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-a-detour-to-contracts) for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the most obvious: concepts are a part of C++20; contracts are *not*.

Second, concepts are *compile-time* requirements; contracts are runtime requirements.

Third, concepts are primarily concerned with the behavior of types. While concepts can be used on values, those values have to be compile-time values since concepts are compile-time constructs. Contracts are primarily concerned with the behavior of values, since any type issues have been worked out by the time a contract has become relevant.

The most important distinction is functional, what they do.

A concept is primarily intended to make a piece of code (usually a template) appear or disappear based on whether something (usually parameters of that template) satisfies a set of requirements. The point of constraining the code is for the definition to essentially not exist if the requirements are not satisfied. When a constraint for a piece of code fails, that's not *a priori* bad; there could be a less constrained or even unconstrained version of the code that executes differently.

Contracts are intended to communicate constraints on the values of runtime objects, with the parameters to a function being the most common case. A contract violation is always a bad thing, and the program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Contracts were approved for C++20, but then the WG21 discovered they weren't as ready as thought.  So rather than put something into C++20 that was half-baked, they made the hard decision to defer contracts to the next C++ standard (C++2b).  Because once they were in the wild, it'd be difficult to redact them.  Contracts were one of the features that Herb Sutter was really looking forward to; the decision was not made lightly.

Comment: @Eljay: "*but then the WG21 discovered they weren't as ready as thought*" I wouldn't say it quite like that. It's more that a bunch of people who looked at the original proposal looked at the version that got into the standard and realized that something had changed *philosophically* in the process of adaptation, such that what they had initially agreed to had turned into something else. And they were not happy with that.

Comment: Re “usually a template”: you can constrain a non-template function only when it’s a member or friend of a templated class.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I’m not sure that the change wasn’t in their *understanding* of that philosophy (and of each other’s understanding of it).

Comment: Contract violations have never been unconditionally undefined behavior—that’s only the “optimized” mode where they’re assumed (which not all proposals have even included).

Comment: @DavisHerring: "*Contract violations have never been unconditionally undefined behavior*" That's what I mean by philosophical changes. In the original idea of contracts, they define preconditions, and precondition violations are always UB (that's how the standard defines "precondition"). There was the possibility of compiling the code in such a way that the UB would exhibit a reliable fail state, but *philosophically* it's still UB. Once you start saying that you can write a "precondition" in a way such that violating it is well-defined behavior, something philosophically has changed.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Failing an (enabled) `assert` is not undefined behavior.  I haven’t done the archaeology to check “the original” contracts proposals, but I would be very surprised by a contracts facility that could not reproduce that (even with configuration).  In fact, my understanding from the authors of those early proposals is that the UB possibility was not their main objective.

Comment: @DavisHerring: "*Failing an (enabled) assert is not undefined behavior.*" Maybe not, but failing a precondition is. Again, that's what "precondition" means. If contracts are just asserts the compiler knows about, then they shouldn't be part of a function's interface like the `[[pre/post]]` grammar suggests. That's what I mean by philosophical issues: the moment you start saying that contracts are how we define preconditions, then you're saying that contracts should *behave* like preconditions. Unless what you're philosophically saying is that preconditions should be asserts.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I think part of the promise of contracts is that “failing a precondition” doesn’t *have* to be UB (but, in many designs, *can* be), whether we consider that to mean that a `[[pre:]]` isn’t truly a precondition (despite the name) or that the meaning of “(behaving like a) precondition” has been broadened.  I guess that means I’m saying that preconditions should *be able to* (but not be required to) be asserts.

Comment: After all this discussion, I am still not seeing any concrete code examples yet. Would you mind explaining more with code examples?

Comment: @Jakob: "*Concrete code examples*" of what? The two features basically have nothing in common; it's like asking for a concrete code example of the difference between an if statement and a template. Basically any example of using one would be an example of *not* using the other.